# How do I get the Children of a ContentPresenter?

Tags: wpf

Using the code I can get a content presenter. I would like to locate the first textbox inside it and set the focus accordingly.

```
Dim obj = TerritoryListViewer.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myModel)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `VisualTreeHelper` static class to crawl controls tree.
This is how it can be accomplished in c# (sorry I'm VB dyslexic))

```
 T FindFirstChild<T>(FrameworkElement element) where T: FrameworkElement
    {
        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
        var children = new FrameworkElement[childrenCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as FrameworkElement;
            children[i] = child;
            if (child is T)
                return (T)child;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            if (children[i] != null)
            {
                var subChild = FindFirstChild<T>(children[i]);
                if (subChild != null)
                    return subChild;
            }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This works for most Framework elememnts, but does not work for me with ContentPresenter

Comment: @John: sounds strange. So what's the problem exactly? Are you unable to find ContentPresenter in the tree, or find child of ContentPresenter? Could it be that when you are searching visual tree is not constructed yet?

Comment: @ Alpha-mouse: You got it!  I wass adding an element to the list and then immediately trying to focus one of its controls.  Using the dispatcher to schedule the focus operation to background priority fixed my problem.

Comment: Add public static in front of the T on the first line to make it compile, then it worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

**`ContentPresenter`** has the only child. You get **the child** simply by

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(yourContentPresenterObj, 0);
```

If you need to go deeper - down to **a first found `TextBox`**, then, yes, you use the more comprehensive approach suggested by @alpha-mouse.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim myContentPresenter = CType(obj, ContentPresenter)
Dim myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate
Dim target = CType(myDataTemplate.FindName("txtQuantity", myContentPresenter), TextBox)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to iterate on all controls of a certain base type placed on a custom canvas which was being used inside an `ItemsControl`.

This Linq expression was used to get those controls from within `MeasureOverride()`:

```
var foobarControls =
    InternalChildren
    .OfType<ContentPresenter>()
    .Where(c => VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(c) > 0)
    .Select(c => VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(c, 0))
    .OfType<FoobarControlBase>();
```

This guards against cases where the `ContentPresenter` had no children. I found in some instances depending on when this was called the visual tree might not be established and as a result the `ContentPresenters` would have no children. (This situation might have been a bug in itself, actually, but nonetheless this code turned out to be reliable.)