# How to get mouse position on part of CustomControl

Tags: c#, wpf

In the making of a customcontrol, I'm trying to get the mouse position on a Canvas which is a container inside my custom control. Problem is, when I put my customcontrol in a testing app, just a grid in a window, what I get is always the mouse position on the window itself but not the mouse position on my customcontrol.

```
public class HueWheel : Control
{
    static HueWheel()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HueWheel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HueWheel)));
    }
    private bool _isPressed = false;
    //private Canvas _templateCanvas = null;
    private Canvas _PART_FirstCanvas;
    private Canvas _PART_SecondCanvas;
    private Slider _PART_Slider;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _PART_FirstCanvas = (Canvas)GetTemplateChild("PART_FirstCanvas");
        _PART_SecondCanvas = (Canvas)GetTemplateChild("PART_SecondCanvas");
        _PART_Slider = (Slider)GetTemplateChild("PART_Slider");
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isPressed)
        {
            const double RADIUS = 150;
            Point newPos = e.GetPosition(_PART_SecondCanvas);
            double angle = MyHelper.GetAngleR(newPos, RADIUS);
            _PART_Slider.Value = (_PART_Slider.Maximum - _PART_Slider.Minimum) * angle  / (2 * Math.PI);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _isPressed = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _isPressed = false;
    }
}
```

This is the xaml contained in Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HueWheel}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HueWheel}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Slider x:Name="PART_Slider">
                        <Slider.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Canvas x:Name="PART_FirstCanvas" Width="300" Height="300">
                                        <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Assets/HueCircle.PNG" Focusable="False" Height="300" Width="300" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                                <TransformGroup>
                                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
                                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                                </TransformGroup>
                                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                                        </Image>
                                        <Ellipse Fill="Transparent" Width="300" Height="300" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"/>
                                        <Canvas x:Name="PART_SecondCanvas">
                                            <Line Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="5" X1="150" Y1="150" X2="150" Y2="0"/>
                                            <Ellipse Fill="Black" Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Left="140" Canvas.Top="30"/>
                                            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                                <RotateTransform CenterX="150" CenterY="150">
                                                    <RotateTransform.Angle>
                                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueAngleConverter}">
                                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Value"/>
                                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Minimum"/>
                                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Maximum"/>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                    </RotateTransform.Angle>
                                                </RotateTransform>
                                            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        </Canvas>
                                    </Canvas>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Slider.Template>
                    </Slider>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Also, the mouse position is output only if mouse is on canvas, so it's kind of half working here... little confuse.

These are the two function I use for angle calculation :

```
public static double GetAngle(double value, double maximum, double minimum)
{
    double current = (value / (maximum - minimum)) * 360;
    if (current == 360)
        current = 359.999;

    return current;
}


public static double GetAngleR(Point pos, double radius)
{
    Point center = new Point(radius, radius);
    double xDiff = center.X - pos.X;
    double yDiff = center.Y - pos.Y;
    double r = Math.Sqrt(xDiff * xDiff + yDiff * yDiff);

    double angle = Math.Acos((center.Y - pos.Y) / r);

    if (pos.X < radius)
        angle = 2 * Math.PI - angle;

    if (Double.IsNaN(angle))
        return 0.0;
    else
        return angle;
}
```

Any hint ?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Absolute Position of element within the window in wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386731/get-absolute-position-of-element-within-the-window-in-wpf)

Comment: that's not a duplicate as I'm trying to get the position within the customcontrol, not within the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_PART_SecondCanvas` and `_PART_FirstCanvas` are null because they belong to the child **Slider**'s control template, and not the "main" **HueWheel** template. Therefore, you can't reach them with `GetTemplateChild()` from HueWheel.

In `OnApplyTemplate()`, you need to find the slider first, then apply its template, and finally call `FindName()` on *that* template to find the canvas elements:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    //_PART_FirstCanvas = (Canvas)GetTemplateChild("PART_FirstCanvas");
    //_PART_SecondCanvas = (Canvas)GetTemplateChild("PART_SecondCanvas");
    _PART_Slider = (Slider)GetTemplateChild("PART_Slider");

    _PART_Slider.ApplyTemplate();

    var sliderTemplate = _PART_Slider.Template;
    _PART_FirstCanvas  = (Canvas)sliderTemplate.FindName("PART_FirstCanvas",  _PART_Slider);
    _PART_SecondCanvas = (Canvas)sliderTemplate.FindName("PART_SecondCanvas", _PART_Slider);
}
```

Source: [How do I get the Children of a ContentPresenter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163754/how-do-i-get-the-children-of-a-contentpresenter/4163885#4163885)

Once you actually find `_PART_SecondCanvas` and `_PART_FirstCanvas`, your `OnMouseMove()` function should do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
Point ControlPos = e.GetPosition (this);
Point WindowPos = e.GetPosition( Application.Current.MainWindow );
```

Will give you - coordinates in the Control and Window coordinates.

Comment: but I want to get the mouse position in my customcontrol code so it is reusable.

Comment: What is "me" in your suggestion ?

Comment: And you also can get relative position directly calling `e.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);`

Comment: Point relativeLocation = _PART_SecondCanvas.TranslatePoint(newPos, Application.Current.MainWindow);    This gave me an error, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  Strange because _PART_SecondCanvas is declared above already...

Comment: so apparently _PART_SecondCanvas, is always null... is it because of how OnApplyTemplate() is invoked or something ? can't find how to fix that but your solution might be the one I think

Comment: Get position directly relative to the main window as in my previous comment. And don't bother about `_PART_SecondCanvas`

Comment: sorry I'm beginner. Trying what your wrote :                 Point newPos = e.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);  give me the exact same result. Position on screen...

Comment: Point newPos = e.GetPosition(_PART_SecondCanvas);
                Point relativeLocation = this.TranslatePoint(newPos, Application.Current.MainWindow);  it gives me the same, this part of the customcontrol is inside a container (in Generic.xaml) could it be the problem ?

Comment: If `_PART_SecondCanvas` is null, you need to fix that. Is `_PART_FirstCanvas ` also null?